# Inject Browser Sync script using the CLI

Tags: javascript, html, command-line, browser-sync

I'm using the [Browser Sync CLI](http://www.browsersync.io/docs/command-line/) to serve some basic html/css/js files and it is telling me to manually include the js script in the html files.

If I was running this with node I could use the [bs-snippet-injector plugin](https://github.com/shakyShane/bs-snippet-injector), but it doesn't look like I can use plugins with the command line tool.

I'm trying to keep this as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I wasn't using the `--server` option; I included that and it works as expected.